# Python TkInter - Multiple Comboboxes copying eachother's selected value

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

I am writing a simple GUI with Tkinter in Python. I need two different comboboxes. However, when I select a value on the first combobox, for some reason it writes that value onto the second, and viceversa, as if they were linked.
How can I unlink them?
Here is my code.

```
subjects = Combobox(frame_answer,text = ("Arial",20), width = 60,height =40) 
subjects.grid(row = 20, column = 50)
questions = Combobox(frame_answer,text = ("Arial",20), width = 60,height = 40)
questions.grid(row = 40, column = 50)
questions["values"] = ["Select","Question1","Queston2","Question3"]
subjects["values"] = ["Select","Math","Science","Spanish"]
```

Comment: show minimal working code with your problem so we could run it and see it. This part of code seems OK.

Answer (score 0):

You passed `text` parameter to both combobox. I believe what you meant is `font` instead.

```
subjects = ttk.Combobox(root,font = ("Arial",20), width = 60,height =40)
questions = ttk.Combobox(root,font = ("Arial",20), width = 60,height = 40)
```

By using `text` you actually created a common `textvariable` for both combobox. You can check by calling `subjects.config()` and `questions.config()`.